# Getting current center of view in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, api

I would like the get the center (coordinates) of the current view. I need it for the geoserver print module.

I've found the code `var center= ol.extent.getCenter({});` but it unfortunately doesn't work. Furthermore I've found a code in the API `(getview.getcenter())`, but it only shows the initial center and it is not changing when I explore on the map.

---

This is my code, it works fine except the center params... It gives back tha same values everytime.

```
var configs = {

    "layout":"A4 portrait",
    "srs":"EPSG:3857",
    "units":"meter",
    "dpi":300,
    "outputFilename": "valami",
    "layers":[
     {baseURL: 'xy', 
            singleTile: false, 
            type: 'OSM', 
            maxExtent: [-20037508.3392,-20037508.3392,20037508.3392,20037508.3392], 
            tileSize: [256, 256], 
            extension: 'png',
            opacity: 1,
            resolutions: [156543.0339, 78271.51695, 39135.758475, 19567.8792375, 9783.93961875, 4891.969809375, 2445.9849046875, 1222.99245234375, 611.496226171875, 305.7481130859375, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.109257067871095, 9.554628533935547, 4.777314266967774, 2.388657133483887, 1.1943285667419434, 0.5971642833709717] 
        },  
{"baseURL":"xy",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "customParams":{},
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["mission:corine_ps"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":true},
{"baseURL":"xy",
        "opacity":1,
        "singleTile":true,
        "customParams":{},
        "type":"WMS",
        "layers":["mission:utak_ps"],
        "format":"image/png",
        "styles":[],
        "overview":true},        
            ],
    "pages":[
        {
        "center":[map.getView().getCenter()[1],map.getView().getCenter()[0]],
        "mapTitle":"",
        "comment":" ",
        "scale": 1000000,
        "rotation":0,
        "icon":""}],
    "legends": [
        {
            "classes": [
                {
                    "icons": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "name": "",
                    "iconBeforeName": true
                }
            ],
            "name": "utak"
        }
    ]
    };

 var printUrl= 'xy?spec='+JSON.stringify(configs);
```

Comment: Are you accessing getCenter in some map change event callback?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

For OpenLayers 2 try

```
map.getCenter()
```

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getCenter

Or OpenLayers 3 use

```
map.getView().getCenter()
```

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getView
   http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#getCenter

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but Your solution is returns the initial center, and this is a predefined value. I need the current center, so I would like to get the actual view's center coordinates.

Comment: Which version of Openlayers are you using?

Comment: Openlayers 3.3.0

Comment: @user52288 using the map.getView().getCenter() should get the current center of the ol.Map object called "map".  Are you sure you're calling the view correctly?  It would help if you could include a snippet or link to some code.

Comment: i've written my code, could you check it? thanks!!

Comment: Hi @user52288, your snippet of code is not actually getting the center of the current map.  Would you be able to post any more of your code (maybe on http://jsfiddle.net/) for more context.